# How to display my combobox value onto my report

Tags: c#, combobox, report

I have form1 and form 2

form1 contains 3 comboboxes : combobox1, comobox2, combobox3 and button1
form2 contains reportviewer1 and for that viewer I created report122

what I need is when I click on button1 the values in the three comboboxes be passed to form2 and be viewed in report122

how to do that

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add three parameters to your report

When you run the report via the button set these parameters using either:

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("[parameter]", [value]));
```

or

```
reportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("[parameter]", [value]));
```

Depending on where the report is held

Comment: SimonPJ .. thanks for your reply .. the report needs to get data from comboboxes values not from sql database.. and kindly explain lil more :)

Comment: My answer is not reliant on an sql database. All you have to do is add the parameters to the report. How/where are you making the report?

Comment: the comboboxes and the button to run the report are in form1 and the report only is in form2

Comment: Yes, but I am more interested in the report itself. If you have the parameters in the report definition we can set them from the form. Are you using some software to make the report?

Comment: no i'm creating the report using the wizard in visual studio 2013 and I haven't set any parameters yet